# is it logical to use SQL Server CE for storing temporary data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce

I'm writing a web app using ASP.NET MVC4 and SQL Server 2012.

At some point in my web app I need to store some data from different pages in my web app and after showing the whole data on a single page to the user, if the user confirmed and there were no validation errors I will store the confirmed data to SQL Server. This web app has a huge number of users.

Is it logical and performance wise to use SQL Server CE as a temporary storage and store the data before confirmation on SQL Server CE?

Are there any other options that I can use?

What about localDb?! is it better to use localDb instead of SQL Server CE in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of company policy and because of SQL Server CE constraint like the number of concurrent connections which  is 256 i used another approach.
I used serialization to keep state of my objects. something like this :

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/647_Creating_Wizard_Using_ASP_NET_MVC_Part_1.aspx

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/652_Creating_Wizard_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Part_2.aspx

```
 public static string Serialize(this object o)
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter(); 
        var formatter =  new LosFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(sw, o);

        return sw.ToString(); 
    }

    public static object Deserialize(this string data)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            return null; 

        var formatter = new LosFormatter();
        return formatter.Deserialize(data); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the session state to store values? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: yes, i have considered the session state, this webapp is written as service as a software and DB team won't allow the dev team to use DB in this scenario so i wanna find a workaround. this temporary data is large so saving , get query and parsing data can be a little messy and difficult. also this data should be serialized to xml and send to another service so i think session state is's that much of help in this case

Comment: It sounds like your workaround is a bit of a hack. What are the reasons the DB team won't let you use the main database? Why not try your SQL CE approach and see if there is any performance issues? I know its not really a proper answer so I hope someone else can help.